# How to find the common value in a property array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in which nodes have a property array. I want to find the common value(s) (if any) in this property array and then set this as a property of the edge that I will create between those two nodes

For example Suppose the graph is:

```
CREATE (n:Person{name:"A", prop:["1", "2", "3", "4"]})
CREATE (m:Person{name:"B", prop:["5", "4", "2", "7"]})
```

I want to create an edge `com_edg` between "A" and "B" as the prop array have values "2" and "4" in common. This `com_edg` edge should have the property prop:`["2", "4"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing Christophe's answer, after compute the common properties between `n` and `n2` you should `CREATE` the relationship between these nodes passing the common nodes array as a property.

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:"A"}), (n2:Person {name:"B"}) 
WITH n, n2, [x IN n.prop WHERE x IN n2.prop] AS common
CREATE (n)-[:com_edge {prop : common}]->(n2)
```

If you are trying to create this relationship between ALL nodes of your graph you should do something like:

```
MATCH (n:Person), (n2:Person) 
WHERE ID(n) > ID(n2)
WITH n, n2, [x IN n.prop WHERE x IN n2.prop] AS common
CREATE (n)-[:com_edge {prop : common}]->(n2)
```

The `WHERE ID(n) > ID(n2)` is used here to guarantee the query will match in only one direction. But note this second query is very expensive because it will consider every pair of node in your graph.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not really graph oriented, this is definitely possible.

```
MATCH (n:Person {name:"A"}), (n2:Person {name:"B"}) 
RETURN [x IN n.prop WHERE x IN n2.prop] AS common
```

-

```
common
[2, 4]
```